# Record that haven't relationship with other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have two tables: users and user_visits.

For example i would get the user_id and name of users that have 0 visited where date > '2014-05-06' and date < '2014-05-11'.

```
USERS TABLE                    USERS_VISITS TABLE

USER_ID |  NAME                USERS_VISIT_ID  |  USER_ID  |  DATE
   1    |  John                       1        |      1    |   2014-05-07
   2    |  Mark                       2        |      1    |   2014-05-08
   3    |  Mike                       3        |      4    |   2014-05-10
   4    |  Steven
```

The result must be:

```
 USER_ID | NAME  | COUNT(*) |
    2    | Mark  |   0      |
    3    | Mike  |   0      |
```

My query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(uv.user_id) AS count_visited, 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_visited uv ON (u.user_id=uv.user_id)  
WHERE uv.date >= '2014-05-06' 
AND uv.date <= '22014-05-11' 
GROUP BY u.user_id
HAVING count_visited = 0;
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Questions with no code get closed.

Comment: Not one shread of code in any of OP's questions. *Well, most of.*

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it using left join

```
select
u.user_id,
u.name
from user u
left join user_visits uv on uv.user_id = u.user_id
AND uv.date >= '2014-05-06' 
AND uv.date <= '22014-05-11' 
where  uv.user_id is NULL
```